# Cannot access properties of object returned by $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a .json file and assigning it to a variable `json` using `$.getJSON(url);` and when I check it with

```
console.log(json);
console.log(typeof json);
```

just to be sure I get this big object with lots of unrelated data: [console.log() result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yd2E.png) 
Full code sample:

```
var json = 0;
function fetchJson(url){
    var json = $.getJSON(url);
    console.log(json);
    console.log(typeof json);
    for(var i in json['responseJSON']){
        console.log(json['responseJSON'][i]);
    }
}
fetchJson('test.json');
```

When I try to iterate through `json['responseJSON']` when page loads I don't get anything at all but the initial `console.log()`'s, but if I copy and paste this in console I get `undefined` as well. If I use

```
var list = "";
for(i in json['responseJSON']) {
    list += json['responseJSON'][i]; 
    return list;
}
console.log(list);
```

instead, it returns empty string.

What I need are values of `type` properties of `objects`[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X84Lc.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous, which means it's making a call to a server, and you cannot predict when that response will come back.  Please review jQuery's documentation, which shows how you must provide a callback function which will run when the request completes and receives a response:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```js
function fetchJson(url){
    var json = $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        // this will run after the response is received.
        console.log(json);
        console.log(typeof json);
        for(var i in json['responseJSON']){
            console.log(json['responseJSON'][i]);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getJSON doesn't directly return JSON. It's asynchronous. You pass it a function that gets called later when the data is returned.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/